# How to run twisted in its own thread and stop properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I'm using twisted in my application and running it in its own thread. Using twisted like this works well but it never stops properly.

Example:

```
# Python 2.7.6
# Twisted==15.4.0

import time
import threading
from twisted.internet import reactor

print("starting reactor")
reactor_thread = threading.Thread(target=reactor.run,
                              kwargs={"installSignalHandlers": False})
reactor_thread.start()
print("reactor started")

time.sleep(1)

print("stopping reactor")
reactor.stop()
print("joining thread")
reactor_thread.join()
print("reactor stopped")  # <- never reached
```

Output:

```
starting reactor
reactor started
stopping reactor
joining thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [Crochet](https://crochet.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.0/). It runs reactors in threads for you.

You should also seriously consider refactoring your application to respect Twisted's idioms. Doing this will permit your application to be composed with other Twisted applications and will ease your maintenance burden. (And then you won't have to run a reactor in a thread.)

Comment: Completely refactoring my application isn't really an option as I rely on dependencies that would also have to be changed. All I want to do is reliably stop the reactor.